# Switching regulator becoming unstable as voltage increases

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

I have a circuit which includes two back-to-back switching regulators. The first is used to take the input of 14 V to 5 V and the second charges a 2-cell lithium battery.

I have verified the problem to be with the first regulator. I cut the connection between the Vout of the 14 V to 5 V regulator and supplied the second regulator with a constant 5 V and it worked as intended.

The problem with the 14 V to 5 V regulator seems to be instability and a changing nominal output voltage. At 6 V Vin the regulator is outputting something close to 5 V, but as the input voltage increases (even to just 14 V), so does the instability and the nominal output voltage increases above 6 V which is too high for my application.

The ICs on the output side are outputting overvoltage protection at about 6 V. On the instability, I see the output voltage on the oscope having +/- 0.7 V on the nominal output voltage. I have fried my IC during testing, but can solder a new one on here shortly.

Why would the nominal output voltage of this regulator potentially rise with input voltage?  If I add more capacitance on the output voltage will it smooth the output signal and prevent these voltage fluctuations?

[image: circuit]

Datasheets:
[RFN1LAM6STFTR](https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/DKDS42/DSANUWW0050009.pdf)
[MAX20077ATCA_VY+](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max20077-max25277.pdf)
[SF-1206SA150M-2](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/sf-1206sa-m.pdf)
[SRP3212-2R2M](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/SRP3212-3002163.pdf)
[865080340001](https://componentsearchengine.com/Datasheets/1/865080340001.pdf)
[865230443003](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/445/865230443003-1726811.pdf)
[CNC5L1X7R1C106K160AE](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/capacitor/ceramic/mlcc/catalog/mlcc_commercial_soft_cnc_en.pdf)

[image: circuit from datasheet]

[image: layout]

[image: regulator properties]

Comment: My suspicion is that you aren't meeting the minimum ESR requirements on the output capacitor. What capacitors are you currently using on the outputs? Are they aluminium electrolytics, tantalums, or MLCCs? What're their voltage ratings? Do you have exact part numbers for them?

Comment: @Polynomial interesting comment.  I will add the mfr# of the capacitors.  In general they are aluminum electrolytic on the output of the 1st switching regulator.  But the 2nd regulator only has X7R ceramic capacitors as it was specified by the manufacturer.

Comment: D101 is apparently called RFN1LAM6**STF** not 5TF. What diode did you end up mounting there?

Comment: @Lundin I will paste the datasheet of the diode, but yes it is STF.  I think this screenshot makes the S look like a 5 though

Comment: @Feynman137 I don't think so. It really looks like you have the wrong part number specified.

Comment: "PGOOD Open-Drain Reset Output. External pullup required." The rest of the datasheet seems to agree too. What happens if you put a 10-20k pull up there? You can also connect it to BIAS apparently.

Comment: @Lundin alright believe me or not, but I edited the question and added all of the datasheets.  Looks like the capacitors were rated at 16V for the 10uF and 25V for the 22uF

Comment: @Lundin I thought this PGood was used for indication that the Vout was good and not necessary for operation.  But if you were to use it you would need a pullup.

Comment: I find nothing in the datasheet that indicates that it should be left floating. Anyway, an easy thing to check. Or well, relatively easy since this is some evil DFN part and hand soldering will be a pain.

Comment: @Lundin Pgood is an open-collector output. If it wasn't allowed to be left floating, the datasheet would say so; outputs are always assumed to be fine to leave floating by default if unneeded. I would be incredibly surprised if adding that pullup resistor does anything to help stability.

Comment: Check if you have problems with ground bounce. It seems most likely to me that the problem is related to PCB layout, so show us a picture of that. An oscilloscope image of the voltage at the switch node would be nice as well.

Comment: Alright let me edit with an image of the layout, I need to replace the IC before I can send scope pictures, because I destroyed it during testing.

Comment: Is the 5-14V from an automobile perhaps?

Comment: It it a lab setup, so Vin should be pretty clean, and is originating from a variable DC power supply.

Comment: @Hearth can you elaborate on why you suspect ground bounce?

Comment: Ground bounce is easy to mess up and easy to overlook when testing (you don't often think to probe the ground pin). I've personally had lots of problems with it in some of my early designs, so it's something I look out for now. I don't really suspect it any more than other possible layout-related problems, though, which is why I asked to see the layout. Incidentally, are you using the 400 kHz or 2 MHz version of the IC?

Comment: Now that you've posted the layout, could you explain why there are no vias directly under the IC? I assume all the ones that are there are going directly to an internal ground plane (if not, that's probably your problem), but why put them all outside the IC instead of internal thermal vias?

Comment: @hearth I agree there should be vias under the IC, there isn't a good reason for putting them on the side here.  This is a 4 layer PCB with ground planes on each layer filling the void spaces so yes this IC's ground pad is connected to the large ground planes by the vias.  Heat dissipation on the board is in general good and I have touched the IC during operation and not noticed any high temperatures.  This is the 2.1MHz version of the IC, I posted the table with all the different flavors of the IC though so you can verify yourself if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the culprit is the layout of the output node of the IC.

The `OUT` pin of this chip is really just a sense pin, that closes the loop with the control of the output voltage. The way you have connected it, there is a lot of common path between the `OUT` pin, and the output side of the inductor.

Imagine all the AC current that is flowing out of the inductor, into the output capacitors: the feedback pin is going to see lots of movement there, missing out on most of the smoothing effect of the caps, because you have hooked it more or less in the mid point.

A better layout would require the feedback signal to have a separate path, ideally connecting directly in the pad of one of the output caps, on a side where no AC current is expected.

It is very well possible that this effect is visible only above a certain input voltage because the duty cycle will be different, and the ripple current in the inductor will change.

One thing you might be able to do to prove this is to cut the track from `OUT` to the caps, soldering a thin wire to it and connecting it on a location where no AC current is flowing, e.g. on the track going to your charger IC.

Here is the proposed cut:
[image: Proposed fix as described above]

In Yellow the cut, in blue a wire going to the pad of a cap.

Comment: And by the way, the way they draw the example schematic on the datasheet is a bit misleading, in my opinion.

Comment: Would you mind drawing the proposed line cut onto the layout screenshot I attached?  I am about 90% certain I understand what you are saying and will try this but I want to be sure.  Also it would be interesting to see how far down you propose reconnecting the capacitors.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: After some testing and modification it is true changing the layout by cutting a trace and attaching a small wire will make this circuit function as intended.  However the location of the necessary cut is slightly different then proposed on 1/30.  See figure 3 (page 15) on the Max datasheet which shows the inductor loop close to the IC and the capacitors closer to the load.  The  C104 and C105 input trace should be cut and reattached to Vout near the top left of the footprint screenshot I attached.